# How to generate an array of 8 bytes , each of these is random number in C

Tags: c

as in the title, and each element of the array `iv` should contain a random number  between 0 and 255 . I have tried like:

```
char iv[8];
char buf[2];
int i, k;
srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i <8; i++){
     k = rand()%256;
     iv[i] = (char)k;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to have mis-typed your `iv` array in the for loop - perhaps you should use some readable names rather than cryptic letters.

Comment: What's the problem?  From visual inspection, the code looks correct (except the mispelling of vi in the inner loop).

There are of course better random number generators than 'srand(time)' and 'rand', but that doesn't mean your code doesn't work as-is if the limitations of that algorithm are acceptable.

Comment: Plus, if there are other better ways, could you please tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `unsigned char` for the array, not `char`.  The former is guaranteed to be able to hold the values from 0 to (at least) 255, but the latter *may* not be able to hold numbers greater than 127.

Comment: And when I use the "unsigned char", I can use it in a function which has a parameter using the type "char"?

Comment: Not in general, but it depends upon the specifics of the function.

Comment: I think you mean "to ((1 << CHAR_BIT)-1)", not "to 255". C does not guarantee 8-bit bytes.

Comment: @unwind: `CHAR_BIT` is guaranteed to be *at least* 8, or to put it another way, `UCHAR_MAX` has to be at least 255, so caf's statement is correct.

Comment: Alok is correct, that was what I was intending to imply.  I have added "(at least)" to clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code. It's a bit excessive and "talkative" when it comes to generating and storing the number, and has magic constants where none are needed, but it should produce the wanted result.

The loop could be shortened to:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof iv; i++)
     iv[i] = (char) rand();
```

Of course the randomness will be limited by whatever implementation of a [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) your compiler and/or library is using.

Comment: keep in mind that for linear congruential PRNGs, the lower bits won't be as 'random' as the higher ones, ie you might want to shift the result of `rand()` before the cast

Answer (score 2):

You can directly assign the return value of rand() mod 256 to the array elements:

```
char iv[8];
int i;
srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i <8; i++)
  iv[i] = rand()%256;
```

This way can see some -ve numbers in the `iv` array when you try to print it as an integer. 
Lets say `rand()%256` gave 255, which is `1111 1111`. Clearly the most significant bit of this is set, so when you try to print it as an integer it will be interpreted as a -ve number.

To avoid getting -ve numbers you'll have to declare the iv as an array of unsigned char:

```
unsigned char iv[8];
```

Comment: I wrote on like this before, but why when I want to see the result of iv[i], like, in the loop: printf(the %d number of iv is %d, i, iv[i]); Then I alway had some of the results being negative....

Answer (score 0):

looks like ur solution could be something like this,

```
char myrand[8];
int *my1,*my2;
my1 = (int*)(myrand);
my2 = (int*)(myrand+4);
srand(time(NULL));
my1 = rand() % 0xffffffff;
my2 = rand() % 0xffffffff;
```

works faster you see.
BTW I assume that int here is 4 bytes :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it as an Initiazation vector ( I guessed it seeing the variable named `iv` ) then it probably has to be unsigned as most cryptographic libraries expect a byte-array of eight unsigned values.

Answer (score 0):

U should print using %u not %d. %u is the printf unsigned symbol, so it want take the sign bit into account, and print all the numbers as positive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for use in a cryptographic algorithm? If so, you maybe shouldn't use rand(), it's not good enough for most cryptographic purposes.

Comment: So which methods are you recommending to generate random numbers for cryptographic purpose?

Comment: Depends on your operating system. Suggest you ask on crypto.stackexchange.com.